# Why do I get back 2 responses of 200 and 204 when using an AJAX call to delete objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've created some sample code below.  You can delete items simply by clicking the text you want to delete (or the li element).

When you look at the network tab when you delete, you get back both a 204 and 200 response.  Why are there two? I'm only making 1 call.

Where the heck is the request method "OPTIONS" coming from?

```js
//Cache DOM
var $content  = $( 'ul' );
var $name  = $( '#name' );
var $bike  = $( '#bike' );
var $addButton = $( '#add-item' );
var $liElems  = $( 'li' );

//Functions


$( function () {

 function addItem( data ) {
  $content.append( '<li id="' + data.id + '">' + data.name + ' likes ' + data.bike + '</li>' );
 }

 $.ajax( {
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/sjm/bikes',
  success: function( response ) {
   $.each( response, function( index, bikes ) {
    addItem( bikes );
   });
  },
  error: function( ) {
   console.log ( 'error loading orders' );
  }
 });

 $addButton.on( 'click', function(){
  var data = {
   name: $name.val(),
   bike: $bike.val()
  };

  $.ajax( {
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/sjm/bikes',
   data: data,
   success: function( response ) {
    addItem( response );
   },
   error: function( ) {
    console.log( 'error while saving' );
   }
  });
 });

 $content.delegate( 'li', 'click', function ( ) {
  var id = $( this ).attr( 'id' );
  var $this = $( this );

  console.log ( 'delete ' + id);
  $.ajax({
   type: 'DELETE',
   url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/sjm/bikes/' + id,
   success: function( response ){
    $this.fadeOut( 300, function ( ) {
     remove( );
    });
   },
   error: function( ){
    console.log( 'error deleting data' );
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
 <section>
  name <input type="text" id="name">
  bike <input type="text" id="bike">
  <button id="add-item">add data</button>
 </section>
 <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe it's a cross-domain ajax thing.  You just focus on the request and response of the DELETE.  If that gives you errors like permission, etc. then look at the OPTION request and response to make sure the api server supports the headers you send.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you try to send a XMLHttpRequest to a different domain than the page is hosted, you are violating the same-origin policy. However, this situation became somewhat common, many technics are introduced.
CORS is one of them.

In short, server that you are sending the DELETE request allows cross domain requests. In the process, there should be a **preflight** call and that is the **HTTP OPTION** call.

So, you are having two responses for the **OPTION** and **DELETE** call.

see [MDN page for CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).